# Make Web Pages act like Unity Apps

Tags: application-development, webapps

Is thee a way to make web pages act like apps?

What I want to do is to split many Chromium pinned tabs into apps. So, for example, I have 2 gmail accounts, 2 tabs in Chromium, and I want separate Chromium instance with Gmail icon in launcher, so I can easily switch to it. I want to do similar thing for Twitter, Google Reader...

Comment: Have you considered going into "Settings" and adding one or more users? Chromium will create a separate profile for each user.

Comment: I want web apps to act like Unity apps, have them in launcher, search and run them from the dash...

Answer (score 0):

For Gmail at least you could install it [as a Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail/pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) and then create a launcher for it by right clicking on its icon and selecting *Create Shortcuts...* :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zYa6X.png]

Same thing goes for any other app found in the Chrome Webstore.

Comment: Yes, but I have multiple gmail accoounts and keep them in separate tabs. This app have no support for that.